# Timeout in RxJava

Tags: java, timeout, rx-java, reactive-programming

I'm new to RxJava, and I need to use the Observable feature in an asynchronous way.

I also need to use timeouts : in my exemple, I want every process to end in 1 second or less.

Here is what I've done for now :

```
public static void hello(String name) throws IOException {
Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.just(name).timeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
    obs2.subscribe(new Action1<String>() {
        @Override
        public void call(String s) {
            if("CCCCC".equals(s)){
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(3200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } 
        System.out.println(s + " " + new Date() +" "+Thread.currentThread().getName());
        }
    });
}

public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {     
    hello("AAAAA");
    hello("CCCCC");
    hello("BBBBBB");
    System.in.read();
}
```

Result :

```
AAAAA Thu Oct 05 09:43:46 CEST 2017 RxIoScheduler-2
BBBBBB Thu Oct 05 09:43:46 CEST 2017 RxIoScheduler-4
CCCCC Thu Oct 05 09:43:49 CEST 2017 RxIoScheduler-3
```

I was actually expecting to get a TimeoutException from the thread named "RxIoScheduler-3"  since it has been sleeping for 3 seconds.

What's wrong with my code and my approach of timeouts in RxJava?

Thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the docs](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timeout.html) the `timeout` operator will:

> mirror the source Observable, but issue an error notification if a particular period of time elapses without any emitted items

So, a timeout is deemed to have occurred if there is a delay in **emitting** events but you have put a delay in **consuming** events and that will not cause a timeout.

If you rework your code to pause during emission then a timeout will occur. For example:

```
public static void hello(String name) throws IOException {
    Observable<String> obs2 = Observable.fromCallable(() -> {
                if ("CCCCC".equals(name)) {
                    // pause for 150ms before emitting "CCCCC"
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(150);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return name;
            }
    ).timeout(100, MILLISECONDS) // timeout if there is a pause in emission of more than 100ms
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());

    obs2.subscribe(s -> System.out.println(s + " " + new Date() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()),
            throwable -> System.err.println(throwable.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + new Date() + " " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
}
```

Using the above form of `hello()` you'll get the following output written to console:

```
AAAAA Thu Oct 05 10:10:33 IST 2017 RxIoScheduler-2
BBBBBB Thu Oct 05 10:10:33 IST 2017 RxIoScheduler-4
TimeoutException Thu Oct 05 10:10:33 IST 2017 RxComputationScheduler-1
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you do not have a control over the method you are using (such as when you are using a library) you can use the [Observable.timer](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/timer.html) operator. You create this before your action (library call).

```
long timeoutInSeconds = 5;
Disposable ssaiTimeout = Completable.timer(
                timeoutInSeconds,
                TimeUnit.SECONDS,
                AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(() -> {
                    // timeout occurred
                    // in case you do not have this method you can use a boolean flag
                    // to see if timeout occured and check agains that in getData
                    libraryClass.cancelRequest();
                    // handle timeout ...
                });

libraryClass.someAsynchronousRequest(new CallbackClass() {
    @Override
    public void getData(Data data) {
        ssaiTimeout.dispose();
        // do your stuff ...
    }
}
```