# Java Spring Runnable task with timeout

Tags: java, spring, runnable

Faced the fact that when the database is unavailable, the queue grows because tasks stop running. What is the best way to set some timeout for tasks executed in method run()? May be there is some good approach with using ExecutorService?

```
@Service
public class AsyncWriter implements Writer, Runnable {
    
    private LinkedBlockingQueue<Entry> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

    private volatile boolean terminate = false;

    private AtomicInteger completedCounter = new AtomicInteger();

    @PostConstruct
    private void runAsyncWriter() {
        Thread async = new Thread(this);
        async.setName("Writer Thread");
        async.setPriority(2);
        async.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!terminate) {
            try {
                Entry entry = queue.take();                
                    dao.save(entry);
                    completedCounter.incrementAndGet();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void write(Entry entry) {
        queue.add(entry);
    }   
}
```

Comment: Either don't run the tasks yourself, but use a `TaskScheduler`, or have a flag, that counts the errors encountered in your `run()` and if the errors surpass a threshold you could use a `Thread.sleep()` statement

Comment: Also you would need another `catch` statement to catch the errors thrown when the database becomes unavailable, else your `run()` would just get terminated after the first exception

Comment: Question: Why exactly do you need to asynchronously save `Entry`s to the database? Is this construct just used for the case *when* the database is unavailable, or do you have a specific use case

Comment: Because this is background, low-priority task. This construct is used always, and it must skip tasks with some timeout when database is unavailable.

Comment: But the main reason is that BlockingQueue blocks the entire application if wouldn't run  asynchronously.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try RxJava
https://www.baeldung.com/rx-java
And you can set your aync funtions
[Timeout in RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46580869/timeout-in-rxjava)

Comment: I think there must be some good approach with ExecutorService